# SherlockListFragment Causing IllegalStateException Must Attach to SherlockListActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I have a class which creates a behindMenu for a Sliding Menu as follows:

```
public class BehindMenuFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity());
    int cats = categories.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < cats; i++) {
        adapter.add(new CategoryItem(categories[i], getIcon(categories[i])));
        }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It gets called from another activity MainActivity with the following code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new BehindMenuFragment ())
    .commit();
```

The above code works fine no problems, I want to insert an Action Bar using ActionBarSherlock to the behind menu I've tried it in every way possible to no avail.

Extending BehindMenuFragment as a SherlockListFragment gives me the following error:

IllegalStateException: BehindMenuFragment must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity

Im at a loss and don't know how to move forward with this problem please help!

Comment: What type of Activity is MainActivity extending now?

Comment: What is a SlidingFragmentActivity?

Comment: Its a library by Jeremy Feinstein https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: That looks like a decent library... I'll have to try it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you haven't done [step four](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#setup-with-actionbarsherlock):

> ### Setup with ActionBarSherlock
>
> 1. Setup as above.
> 2. Checkout a clean copy of ActionBarSherlock and import into your Eclipse workspace.
> 3. Add ActionBarSherlock as a dependency to SlidingMenu
> 4. Go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend `Sherlock___Activity` instead of `___Activity`.

Having never worked with this library I would *guess* that you should change MainActivity to:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockSlidingFragmentActivity {
```

Now you can use a SherlockListFragment:

```
public class BehindMenuFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
```

And add Sherlock's ActionBar.

Comment: I can't believe this and I had to do this yesterday for another activity. Learned a good lesson today! Thank you Thank you Sam!!